# Date of privileges implemented on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, privileges

Can someone tell me the date that the privileges system was implemented on Stack Overflow? Or were restrictions for new users in place from the beginning?

Comment: This should have most of the changes after the beta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: Thank you Ben for the link. Looking at @jonrsharpe 's answer, it's possible that SO implemented only privileges regarding posts' moderation, but not such as creating posts, commenting or other general activities, from the beginning. So I will have a good time of reading about evolution of SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read [the article that announced Stack Overflow's public launch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html) (dated September 15th, 2008), which already refers to reputation gaining what we now refer to as *"privileges"*:

> Once you’ve earned a little bit of reputation in the system (and there are all kinds of ways to earn reputation), you can edit questions and answers.